# SQL how to convert array to values for use in IN clause

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, in-clause

Working in Postgres SQL:

```
create table TAB1 ( X int, Y varchar(12));

insert into TAB1 values (1, 'ABC');
insert into TAB1 values (2, 'BCD');
insert into TAB1 values (3, 'EFG');
```

My query argument comes in as a comma separated string: 'ABC,BCD'

I am trying to construct the query below, but getting an error:

```
select * 
from TAB1 
where Y in (STRING_TO_ARRAY('ABC,BCD', ','));
```

ERROR:

> Operator does not exist: character varying = text[]

My question is how to convert 'ABC,BCD' to a list of values to use in the IN CLAUSE. Prefer answer in SQL query, not method or function. Thanks.

Comment: Answer posted in your suggestion was way too complicated for the question I have posted. The answers this question received are much more to the point and uses SQL features which I wanted. I could have implemented it in a Java method instead of the SQL function in the post you suggested. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an array, you need to use the `ANY` operator:

```
select * 
from TAB1 
where Y = any( STRING_TO_ARRAY('ABC,BCD', ',') );
```

Comment: perfect. I find it amazing it is now I encounter the key word ANY in SQL. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to get the results that you want is instead of `IN` to use the operator `LIKE`:

```
select * from TAB1
where ',' || 'ABC,BCD' || ',' like '%,' || Y || ',%'
```

replace the concatenation operator `||` with the operator that works in your db, (like `+` for SQL Server) or the function `concat()`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=91fd7908d20f29661616f8e29c6d1ad1).
Results:

```
>  X | Y  
> -: | :--
>  1 | ABC
>  2 | BCD
```

Comment: This is a solution for standard sql and I posted it before you tagged with Postgresql. Chek @a_horse_with_no_name's solution if it suits your code.

Comment: I gave your answer a +up. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Use this utility function which converts array to comma separated values to be used inside IN clause:

```
const arrayToInClauseString = (arrayData) => {
   return arrayData
     .map((item, index, all) => {
       if (index === all.length - 1) {
         return `"${item}"`;
       } else {
         return `"${item}",`;
       }
     })
     .join("");
 };
```